# Uniform convergence of the factors of the Weierstrauss Sigma Function

Tags: complex-analysis

On of the elliptic functions, the Weierstrass sigma function is defined as for a lattice $\Omega$ as:

> $$\sigma(z)=z\cdot{\prod_{\omega\in\Omega}}^\prime g(\omega,z),$$ where $$g(\omega,z)=(1-z/\omega)\exp\left(\frac{z}{\omega}+1/2\cdot \left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^2\right).$$

Now, in my textbook it says that on a compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb{C},$ as $|\omega|\rightarrow \infty,$ where $\Omega$ has its natural order, it follows that $g(w,z)\rightarrow 1$ uniformly, and I can't seem to prove why.

I understand that $|\omega|\rightarrow \infty$ and $K$ being compact implies it is bounded. I tried to show that

$$\sup_{z\in K}|g(z,w)-1|\rightarrow 0;$$

as the supremum will be for some $z_0\in K,$ then it is sufficient to show that
$$\left|(1-z_0/\omega)\exp\left(\frac{z_0}{\omega}+1/2\cdot \left(\frac{z_0}{\omega}\right)^2\right)-1\right|\rightarrow 0,$$

but I can't find a way to use that $|\omega|\rightarrow \infty.$

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is a lattice in this context? There are 5 tags including the noun 'lattice': `lattice-orders`, `integer-lattices`, `vector-lattices`, `lattices-in-lie-groups` and `banach-lattices`. I suspect the first one (chosen) doesn't apply.

Comment: Consider $f(z,w) := g(z,w^{-1})$ an entire function. Then one can instead  may consider $f(z,w)$ when $z \in K$ and $\omega$ converges to $0$ in some compact neighbourhood $K^\prime$ of $0$

Comment: @amrsa, you are probably right, let me change that.

Comment: @PCeltide Good, but it seems to be the case that some tag about lattices must apply. From the relevant definition you should make a better judgment. It's just that wrong tags bring the attention of people errounously.

Comment: @user2628206, thank you, that makes it nice clean!

Comment: @amrsa, I will keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: Grand! In general some sort of möbius (i.e. $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z - c}$) transform are very helpful with these kind of convergence problems - but exact method differs from problem to problem.